# get object from other scene

Tags: python, game-engine

i want to get object from other scene like this script

> scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()
>
> player=scene.objects['player']

for example from scene named "Hud"

how can i do it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the scene has to be loaded to have access to :

```
# to load the scene
bge.logic.addScene('Hud')

#find the scene and object
scenes = bge.logic.getSceneList()
for scene in scenes :
    if scene.name == 'Hud':
        player = scene.objects['player']
```