# Changing material in a non active scene from python (BGE)

Tags: python, game-engine, objects, scene

I have two scenes, sceneA and sceneB, which I run in game mode. While I am running sceneA, I would like to change a material in sceneB (but only at a later stage move to sceneB).

I can access the objects in sceneA while in A by

```
    scene = bge.logic.getCurrentScene()
    print(scene.objects)
```

Is their a way how I could access the objects in sceneB, while in A?

```
    scenelist = getSceneList()
```

only returns scene A as that is the one who is active and

```
    sceneB.objects
```

gives an error of name 'sceneB' is not defined.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: you have to load scene B  so you can access it, see this answer http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28920/5113